# Converting lists into columns with boolean values in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a table that contains a column which contains a list with numbers in them.

One such list could contain values like [4, 7, 13].

How can this be transformed into columns that have a predefined prefix (e.g. "vendor.") and then the value (e.g. 4) as the column name?

Also, for all generated columns, the value should be true if the number was in the values list and false if it wasn't in the values list.

E.g. given the following table:

| row_id | vendors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [4,7,13] |
| 2 | [1,7,13] |

The following should be created:

| row_id | vendor.1 | vendor.4 | vendor.7 | vendor.13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | true | true | true |
| 2 | true | false | true | true |

Is this possible in PowerQuery?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

Replace the [ and ] with nulls

Split the vendors column on , into rows

Change the vendor column to pre-append "vendor."

Add column = True

Pivot

Replace nulls with False

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"[","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"vendors"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","]","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"vendors"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value1", {{"vendors", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "vendors"),
#"preappend title" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"vendors", each "vendor."&_, type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"preappend title", "data", each true),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[vendors]), "vendors", "data"),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,false,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"))
in  #"Replaced Value2"
```

[image]